# Determining IP address and port of an incoming TCP/IP connection in Erlang

Tags: sockets, erlang, tcp

I would like to fetch the IP address and port number of an incoming TCP/IP connection. Unfortunately `gen_tcp`'s `accept` and `recv` functions only give back a socket, while `gen_udp`'s `recv` function also gives back the address information. Is there a straightforward way to collect address information belonging to a socket in Erlang?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `inet/peername 1`. From the [Erlang inet docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html):

> peername(Socket) -> {ok, {Address, Port}} | {error, posix()}
>
> Types:
>
> Socket = socket()
>   Address = ip_address()
>   Port = int()
>
> Returns the address and port for the other end of a connection.