# ejabberd ip address

Tags: erlang, sockets, ip, ejabberd

Does anyone know if there's a direct way to map an IP address to a user logged into ejabberd?  I found an indirect way by modifying ejabberd_receiver.erl and calling inet:peername(Socket) from here: [Determining IP address and port of an incoming TCP/IP connection in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240312/determining-ip-address-and-port-of-an-incoming-tcp-ip-connection-in-erlang)

but there doesn't seem to be a way to link a socket to a user after they've successfully been authenticated.  If anyone knows of a way, please let me know!  Thanks.

Comment: You might fine better help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your installation, you might want to run ejabberd_sm:dirty_get_sessions_list/0 and call get_user_ip/3 on each triple to implement a reverse lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use From argument from **handle_call** or **handle_info** calls to get User, Server, Resource information. Then call:

```
Info = ejabberd_sm:get_user_info(User, Server, Resource), 
{ip, {Ip, Port}} = lists:keyfind(ip, 1, Info).
```